# "I will send an email to manager and copy you on that." Is this correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence

1) I will send an email to Rick and copy you on that.

2) I will send an email to Rick and I will copy you on that.

Which of the above is correct?

Comment: They're both fine. Deletion of repeated elements is a normal part of English, and if you need help understanding this you should be using [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are essentially correct, although the second example requires a comma between "Rick" and "and."

In a **compound sentence** the two independent clauses must be separated by a comma and a conjunction, or by a semicolon (without a conjunction).

The second rendering, with its comma, places somewhat more emphasis on the speaker's promise to cc: the message.